# Why does a <h2> Header clip the succeeding SVG element?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dimple.js

I tried a basic visualization with d3.js and dimple from udacity, however, I observe an effect I can't explain:

I run a simple dimple.js visualization which is embedded in an svg element which works fine.
When I preceed the svg element with a  header, ... - see line 27

```
d3.select("body").append("h2").text("World Cup Attendance");
```

...the chart within the svg element seems to get translated and clipped at the bottom. 
Why does adding this line alter the chart?
To my understanding the SVG element is an independent element which has its own relative coordinate system - not affected by preceding html elements...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      circle.dimple-series-1 {
        fill: red;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(data) {

      /*
        D3.js setup code
      */

          "use strict";
          var margin = 75,
              width = 1400 - margin,
              height = 600 - margin;

        // this line moves the labels of the x axis 
         d3.select("body").append("h2").text("World Cup Attendance");

          var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin)
              .attr("height", height + margin)
            .append('g')
                //.attr("transform", "translate(0,-30)")
                .attr('class','chart');
          var data = [
              { "year":"1980", "attendance":245000 },
              { "year":"1984", "attendance":245000 },
              { "year":"1988", "attendance":304400 }
            ];

      /*
        Dimple.js Chart construction code
      */

          var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
          var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "year"); 
          myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "attendance");

          x.dateParseFormat = "%Y";
          x.tickFormat = "%Y";
          // x.timeInterval = 4;

          myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
          myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.scatter);
          myChart.draw();
        };

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    Use D3 (not dimple.js) to load the TSV file
    and pass the contents of it to the draw function
    */
    draw();
  // d3.tsv("world_cup.tsv", draw);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe. Here's what it looks like when I run your code on my machine in Chrome: http://cl.ly/image/1o3k272M2i00.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
That's interesting, yes with Chrome it works as designed, I can confirm. But with firefox (version 34.0.5) I have half of the labels clipped. That's why I tried on line 34 (now commented out) to translate the SVG and then the whole chart is visible...

It seems an issue with firefox then.. I would embed a screenshot of the clipped chart here, if I would know how..

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess it's because of this dimple method, "[dimple._parentHeight](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/dd7009ef20785c3c0e840e968bdda0dc672f0ac2/src/methods/_parentHeight.js)". It calculates the height of the parent element of the svg and has a workaround for a firefox issue, so you could see a difference based on the container of the svg (body, in this instance) having or not having another element in it.

Your best bet (and what I've done for a similar reason) is to wrap the svg inside a div which will compute the height correctly :

```
       var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .append("svg")
```

Comment: Bingo! That's terrific how quickly you found it out and provided the fix!! Thanks so much, I was thinking I don't get the basics right...